# UIView not loading in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Trying to load an `UIView` into a header of a table view in a `UIViewController` and I'm doing the following but it's not working for some reason. The view is being added but the graph isn't being displayed..

In the `UIView`,

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self symbolLookup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)symbolLookup{

    MAFinance *stockQuery = [MAFinance new];
    // set the symbol
    stockQuery.symbol = @"goog";

    /* set time period
     MAFinanceTimeFiveDays
     MAFinanceTimeTenDays
     MAFinanceTimeOneMonth
     MAFinanceTimeThreeMonths
     MAFinanceTimeOneYear
     MAFinanceTimeFiveYears
     */
    stockQuery.period = MAFinanceTimeOneMonth;
    [stockQuery findStockDataWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *stockData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // we've got our data
            self.allData = stockData;
            NSLog(@"%@", [[self.allData objectForKey:@"StockInformation"] allKeys]);

            self.pricesArray = [stockData objectForKey:@"Prices"];
            self.datesArray = [stockData objectForKey:@"Dates"];
            self.maV = [MAStockGraph new];
            self.maV.delegate = self;
            [self addSubview:self.maV];
            [self.maV reloadGraph];

        } else {
            // something went wrong, log the error
            NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

And in the view controller,

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    StockView *view = [[StockView alloc]initWithFrame:tableView.frame];
    return view.maV;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `maV` a value inside a (presumably) asynchronous call: `findStockDataWithBlock`.

Instead, instantiate the view outside of the block and then update its values when the block is executed.

```
self.maV = [MAStockGraph new];
self.maV.delegate = self;
[stockQuery findStockDataWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *stockData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // we've got our data
        self.allData = stockData;
        NSLog(@"%@", [[self.allData objectForKey:@"StockInformation"] allKeys]);

        self.pricesArray = [stockData objectForKey:@"Prices"];
        self.datesArray = [stockData objectForKey:@"Dates"];
        [self.maV reloadGraph];

    } else {
        // something went wrong, log the error
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

---

I am compelled to point out that what you're doing is very strange. Why are you creating a view in order to get one of its subviews and throw away the original view? Consider restructuring this so that you create a `MAStockGraph` directly and pass it an external datasource, or pass back the view you created instead of a subview.

Comment: didn't work! And the reason why I'm doing it this way is because I feel like it would be easier when I try to make multiple graphs in the future

Comment: Yep. The graph's initial view is loaded. The data just isn't being loaded though

Comment: Does `reloadGraph` get called? Do your delegate methods get called? Is it expecting you to also attach a datasource?

Comment: The data source is an internet server and the delegate methods have been implemented within the view that is being called. I've tested the graph within the tableview and it worked perfectly. Now that I made a UIView out of it, it stopped working...

Answer (score 0):

in you block ,after [self.maV reloadGraph]; just call  -[setNeedsDisplay] to display the new result.

Comment: May be your maV is outside or too small, can not be seen in your parent view. So i think you can debug in the [self addSubview:self.maV]; to see the self and self.mav state.